# How to make a query correctly with API criteria?

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria-api

I am implementing that query with the criteria API , but I manage to obtain the data correctly, the strange thing I see is that when reviewing the query in the hibernate console it shows me that it is making another query with other properties.
I can't understand where the data is passing that changes the query and occupies another table

This shows me in the console

```
select tme_cod - 3000 ,tme_des 
from odepa.dbo.T_tip_mer 
where tme_cod = 3019
```

This is the method created in criteria

```
@Override
public List<Empresa> companiesMar() throws DataAccessException {
    List<Empresa> empresas = new ArrayList<Empresa>();
    DetachedCriteria  criteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Empresa.class, "emp");

    //SELECT
    criteria.setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
    .add(Projections.property("emp.empCod").as("id"))
    .add(Projections.property("emp.empDes").as("descripcion")));
    
    //WHERE
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("emp.empCod", ConstantPreciosMar.EMP_COD));
    return empresas;
}
```

This is the sql query, I am working with SyBase

```
SELECT emp_cod - 3000, emp_des 
FROM odepa.dbo.T_empresa 
WHERE emp_cod = 3019
```

It is in the entity that I am using to create the query with criteria

```
@Entity(name = "T_empresa")
@Table(name = "T_empresa", catalog = Constant.CATALOG_ODEPA, schema = Constant.SCHEMA_DBO)
@Cacheable
public class Empresa implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3570090775261419284L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "emp_cod")
    private Short empCod;

    @Column(name = "emp_com_cod")
    private Short empComCod;

    @Column(name = "emp_des")
    private String empDes;

    @Column(name = "emp_raz_soc")
    private String empRazSoc;

    @Column(name = "emp_gir_com")
    private String empGirCom;

    @Column(name = "emp_dir")
    private String empDir;

    @Column(name = "emp_fon")
    private String empFon;

    @Column(name = "emp_fax")
    private String empFax;

    @Column(name = "emp_cas")
    private String empCas;

    @Column(name = "emp_des_con")
    private String empDesCon;

    @Column(name = "emp_hora_cierre_envio")
    private Time empHoraCierreEnvio;

    @Column(name = "emp_hora_cierre_edicion")
    private Time empHoraCierreEdicion;

    @Column(name = "emp_hora_publicacion")
    private Time empHoraPublicacion;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "empresa", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<TSisEmp> sisEmp;

    public Empresa() {
        super();
    }

    public Short getEmpCod() {
        return empCod;
    }

    public void setEmpCod(Short empCod) {
        this.empCod = empCod;
    }

    public Short getEmpComCod() {
        return empComCod;
    }

    public void setEmpComCod(Short empComCod) {
        this.empComCod = empComCod;
    }

    public String getEmpDes() {
        return empDes;
    }

    public void setEmpDes(String empDes) {
        this.empDes = empDes;
    }

    public String getEmpRazSoc() {
        return empRazSoc;
    }

    public void setEmpRazSoc(String empRazSoc) {
        this.empRazSoc = empRazSoc;
    }

    public String getEmpGirCom() {
        return empGirCom;
    }

    public void setEmpGirCom(String empGirCom) {
        this.empGirCom = empGirCom;
    }

    public String getEmpDir() {
        return empDir;
    }

    public void setEmpDir(String empDir) {
        this.empDir = empDir;
    }

    public String getEmpFon() {
        return empFon;
    }

    public void setEmpFon(String empFon) {
        this.empFon = empFon;
    }

    public String getEmpFax() {
        return empFax;
    }

    public void setEmpFax(String empFax) {
        this.empFax = empFax;
    }

    public String getEmpCas() {
        return empCas;
    }

    public void setEmpCas(String empCas) {
        this.empCas = empCas;
    }

    public String getEmpDesCon() {
        return empDesCon;
    }

    public void setEmpDesCon(String empDesCon) {
        this.empDesCon = empDesCon;
    }

    public Time getEmpHoraCierreEnvio() {
        return empHoraCierreEnvio;
    }

    public void setEmpHoraCierreEnvio(Time empHoraCierreEnvio) {
        this.empHoraCierreEnvio = empHoraCierreEnvio;
    }

    public Time getEmpHoraCierreEdicion() {
        return empHoraCierreEdicion;
    }

    public void setEmpHoraCierreEdicion(Time empHoraCierreEdicion) {
        this.empHoraCierreEdicion = empHoraCierreEdicion;
    }

    public Time getEmpHoraPublicacion() {
        return empHoraPublicacion;
    }

    public void setEmpHoraPublicacion(Time empHoraPublicacion) {
        this.empHoraPublicacion = empHoraPublicacion;
    }

    public Set<TSisEmp> getSisEmp() {
        return sisEmp;
    }

    public void setSisEmp(Set<TSisEmp> sisEmp) {
        this.sisEmp = sisEmp;
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, your question is confusing. You use certain set of API call criteria **and** you're able to get the correct data (which would suggest you had the criteria correctly in the first place)? Also, could you show which ones are the two query results? Which is the one you're not intending to get?

Comment: This is what the console shows me when I run the program
`select tme_cod - 3000 ,tme_des 
from odepa.dbo.T_tip_mer 
where tme_cod = 3019 `
 Which I don't want it to be since I'm not working with that table in the query.

This is the query that I need to execute, the one that works with the table T_empesa

`SELECT emp_cod - 3000, emp_des 
FROM odepa.dbo.T_empresa 
WHERE emp_cod = 3019`